# How to prevent a UIView from momentarily disappearing upon a tap of the clear button in a UITextField?

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

I'm running into an issue I cannot figure out how to resolve. I have a `UITextField` that allows a user to enter text to search.

Initially the `UIView` is hidden.

Below the `UITextField` is a `UIView` that gets triggered (hidden = false) when the user taps inside the `UITextField`.

```
func textFieldShouldBeginEditing(textField: UITextField) -> Bool
{
    inSearchModeView.hidden = false
    return true
}
```

Below the `UITextField` is also a `UITableView` that contains the results of the search. I have it set up where if the user taps anywhere outside the `UITextField`, the keyboard dismisses. However, to ensure that I'm able to select the contents of the `UITableView` if there are any returnable results, I've set this up:

```
func gestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldReceiveTouch touch: UITouch) -> Bool
{
    if touch.view.self == videosTableView.self
    {
        return false
    }

    print("test")
    self.inSearchModeView.hidden = true

    return true
}
```

I would like to have the `inSearchModeView` remain visible when the Clear button is tapped.

The problem is, if I type a text, then hit the Clear button, there were be 1/2 a second moment where the `inSearchModeView` disappears, then reappears again. Or, if I hold the Clear button, I see the `inSearchModeView` disappears, and upon release of the Clear button, it reappears and remain visible again.

I noticed that with the print statement, I see `gestureRecognizer` is called when I tap the Clear button, even though it's within the `UITextField`.

How can this be fixed to where my `inSearchModeView` remains visible unless I tap outside the `UITextField`?

Here's my tap gesture code:

```
viewDidLoad
{ 
    let tap: UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self,     
    action: "dismissKeyboard")
        view.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
}

func dismissKeyboard()
{
    // Causes the view (or one of its embedded text fields) to resign the first responder status.
    view.endEditing(true)
}
```

Thanks

Comment: where r u adding gesture ?

Comment: @iAnurag: added more code for clarity

Comment: y r u adding UITouch parameter in gesture method? any specific reason?

Answer (score 0):

Solved my issue thanks to iAnurag's comments regarding UITouch.

I removed that function and it now works as intended.